# Opensource Inventory management desktop application

Tags: open-source, desktop, inventory, inventory-management

I am a .Net developer and i have to make an Inventory management system. 
So, i am looking for an opensource Inventory management system in C#/VB.Net.

.Net is my first preference but i can consider other options as well.

So, my question is:
1- Can anyone give me a link to a good opensource desktop Inventory software ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start looking at codeplex.com

http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=Inventory&sortBy=Relevance&licenses=|&ac=3

Comment: ahan. Almost all of the projects have very low downloads. Can you suggest any ?

Comment: Nope, I have no suggestions that I have used sorry. This site was just the first I thought of and where I would have started

Comment: ahan i actually looked into sourceforge first during my R&D but all the solutions were either in PHP or Java.

Comment: These are actually C# projects on codeplex

Comment: Yea i figured that out. Thank you by the way. I will try different projects and see which one suites me.